# How to replace multiple old file located at different location with the new files in Mac OS using script?

Tags: scripting, macintosh

I've some new files in a folder A. I want to replace the old files which are located in different folders (ex. B, C, D), with the new files. Is there any way to do this in one shot by writing some script in Mac OS?

For example, the new files are located in `/Updatede`, and have names such as: `flower1.jpg`, `flower2.jpg`, `flower3.jpg`.

Now I want to replace below old files

```
/Workarea/AssetGroupOne/flower1.jpg 
/Workarea/AssetGroupTwo/flower2.jpg 
/Workarea/AssetGroupThree/flower3.jpg
/Workarea/AssetGroupSix/flower1.jpg
```

I want to be specific like `/Updated/flower1.jpg` should replace only the `/Workarea/AssetGroupOne/flower1.jpg` not the `/Workarea/AssetGroupSix/flower1.jpg`

Note: I have more files, but for the sake of brevity, I have not listed them all here.

Comment: Yes. Can you give an example of the file/directory names (from and to)?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question.

Comment: Why do you want to use a script for this?

Comment: Are you sure about the directories starting with `/`? Aren't they located in your users home folder?

Comment: So how can we know what the target of each file is? How can we know that `/Updated/flower1.jpg` should replace only  `/Workarea/AssetGroupOne/flower1.jpg` and not `/Workarea/AssetGroupSix/flower1.jpg`? Can you create a text file with the file name and the target for each file?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Updated &&
for i in *
do
        find /Workarea -name "$i" -exec cp -f /Updated/"$i" {} \;
done
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/22142)

Comment: Working fine. This solution replaces every file in /Workarea, including subdirectory, which matches with file in the /Updated directory. Is there any way to be more specific like /Updated/flower1.jpg should replace only the /Workarea/AssetGroupOne/flower1.jpg not the /Workarea/AssetGroupSix/flower1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Updated
mv flower1.jpg /Workarea/AssetGroupOne/
mv flower2.jpg /Workarea/AssetGroupTwo/
mv flower3.jpg /Workarea/AssetGroupThree/
```

I wonder though, writing the script takes longer than just moving the files in Finder (or typing the commands above into the command line).

Comment: I need to do this repeatedly for several files.

Comment: @Shubham we can't help you if you give us a small piece of information every time. Edit your question and explain what you actually need. How can we know what files need to be moved where?

Comment: I am assuming the OP did not bore us with the 1000s of screen fulls of file names, as it would have added nothing to understanding (except to say there is to much to do manually).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Which is why the answer by msp9011 probably is on the right track by figuring out where the updated files belong to.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor an indication of whether the files in `/Updated` are in a single directory, of whether they all need to be copied, if there can be file name collisions, if multiple files with the same name can be in different `Workarea` directories, and such details would be helpful.

Comment: @terdon I've added some more information to my question.